# How to pass a struct as an argument of a function

Tags: function, go, struct

I have several configuration JSON files, each of which has a specific struc type for each file

currently I created a function per file/struct name:

```
type ConfigOne struct {
    App     string `json:"app"`
    Web     string `json:"web"`
    Archive string `json:"archive"`
}

type ConfigTwo struct {
    Options string `json:"options"`
    Source  string `json:"source"`
    Backup  bool `json:"backup"`
}
    
func ReadJsonConfigOne(file string, config *ConfigOne) error {
    str := GetContentFile(file)
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), config)
}

func ReadJsonConfigTwo(file string, config *ConfigTwo) error {
    str := GetContentFile(file)
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), config)
}

func main() {
    One := ConfigOne{}
    err := ReadJsonConfigOne("file_one.json", &One)
    
    Two := ConfigTwo{}
    err := ReadJsonConfigTwo("file_two.json", &Two)
    
    ../..
}
```

How to use only one function and passing a the struct as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func ReadJsonConfig(file string, config interface{}) error {
    str := GetContentFile(file)
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), config)
}
```

Usage

```
func main() {
    One := ConfigOne{}
    err := ReadJsonConfig("file_one.json", &One)
    
    Two := ConfigTwo{}
    err := ReadJsonConfig("file_two.json", &Two)
    
    ../..
}
```

Use interface as function parameter.